# installed opencv but cant import it in both vscode and IDLE

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

(base) PS C:\Users\LENOVO> pip install opencv-python
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.7.0.68)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.0 in c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.21.5)
(base) PS C:\Users\LENOVO> py
Python 3.9.11 (tags/v3.9.11:2de452f, Mar 16 2022, 14:33:45) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import cv2
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

``Python 3.9.11 (tags/v3.9.11:2de452f, Mar 16 2022, 14:33:45) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

> > > import cv2 as cv
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in 
> > > import cv2 as cv
> > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
> > > `

how do i solve this

(base) PS C:\Users\LENOVO> pip install opencv-python
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.7.0.68)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.0 in c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.21.5)
(base) PS C:\Users\LENOVO> py
Python 3.9.11 (tags/v3.9.11:2de452f, Mar 16 2022, 14:33:45) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import cv2
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

this is what i wanted to do import open cv it has been installed via anaconda